# Как извлечь msi из exe установщика?

Tags: install, msi

Часто в exe установщиках внутри есть msi, если открыть установщик iTunes, то внутри будет это:
[image: iTunes installer inside]

Но если открыть, например, установщик JRE, то внутри будет вот это:
[image: JRE installer inside]

Если запустить такой установщик, то msi можно найти где-то в AppData, но так как это нужно для целей автоматизации, то такой метод плохо подходит.

Есть ли способ извлечь или скомпилировать msi из такого установщика?

Comment: Попробуйте `installFile.exe /extract` выведет запрос пути для разворачивания файлов

Comment: далеко не у всех инсталлеров есть такой флаг

Comment: попробуйте просто `/?`. Возможно у экзешника есть флаги автоматической "тихой" установки и разворачивать msi не нужно

Comment: это да, но вопрос, можно ли вытащить мсай

Answer (score 0):

Можно через скрипт в PowerShell. Если надо можно написать батник. Разархивируем файлы в папку:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace("C:\Script\a.zip")
MkDir("C:\Script\a")
foreach ($item in $zip.items()) {
  $shell.Namespace("C:\Script\a").CopyHere($item)
}
```

Потом поиск файлов с расширением .msi:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Script\*.msi" -Recurse
```